# Point files for isochrones using qneat

Tags: qgis

I am trying to generate isochrones from a set of cable railway stations. Following a tutorial, I use qneat3 iso area as polygons (from layer). At certain point, I'm being asked to load a point file. I load a shape file of stations where I'm interested to find its isochrones, which I asume it has needed info , and when running it,  I obtain this:

Dataset has wrong geometry type. Got PointZ dataset but expected Point dataset instead.

I don't know what kind of file I'm supposed to feed in, I only have shape files (and those attached to it). Please try to be as clear as possible since my background is not in this field.

Edit: I've added a screenshot from file, I guess it won't help much, since attribute table can't be opened

[image]

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of your attribute table?

Comment: Sure, I'm editing this post and adding it, but as you can see, attribute table it's not even highlighted, so I can't even open it.